# Android Webview in background

Tags: android, html, asp.net, authentication, webview

I am new here. I need some help about the WebView in Android. I would like to load a webpage in webview but i need it to be hidden from the user's view. My intention is to login to an aspx page and then be able to fill fields in a form and click send. I have tried to use the http post method but it seems to have problems handling the cookies.

I want to include two input fields for the login form in the screen. The user will enter his credentials and then i will get them, insert them to the according fields of the real login form in the webview and click the login button in the webview page. After login i need to click a hyperlink in the page and then fill two fields in another form and click send. This is the whole process i need to take place.

Is this whole thing even possible to come true? thanks a lot for your time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is considered a bad practice to get capture login data, because user won't know what your app may do with his data before actual login. But if it is your own website (so either way the data is kept in your own services), then you may try two-way communication with use of Java<>JavaScript bindings as described here: [addJavascriptInterface()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

EDIT

```
class JsObject {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getTypedPass() { return passwordEdit.getText(); }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getTypedLogin() { return loginEdit.getText(); }
}
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
webView.loadUrl("http://mypage.com/login.aspx");
...
//after loading page
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        //You can use getTypedPass() and getTypedLogin() in any function
        //that exists on page, so you can call them from:
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:getAndroidCredentials()");
    }
});
```

Comment: it is my own site so either way the data of the users will end to my server.. I just need some way to figure it out the easy way because there are problems with the cookies handling using the http post.